# Is there an equivalent of make -k option in msbuild?

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, bamboo

If you provide -k option (keep-going) to make, it will carry on building everything that can be built an return an error code at the end (echo $? something different from 0).

Now, I know that msbuild has the option ContinueOnError, but it works in a slightly different way. The build will carry on till the end, the number of errors will be printed, but if you query the return state of the run (echo %ERRORLEVEL%) the value is 0, basically a successful build. Obviously this is confusing our CI system (Bamboo).

Is there a way to have the same behavior in msbuild (basically "make -k")?

**Note**

msbuild version used: Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 3.5.30729.5420
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.5485]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *might* be able to achieve what you want by grabbing the exit code from the build task(s) on which you set `ContinueOnError`, in a manner similar to that from this Q&A: [MSBuild targets to run all tests, even if some fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687255/msbuild-targets-to-run-all-tests-even-if-some-fail), and use it to finally fail your overall build.

Note: this is based just on readings, I'm not actually using msbuild.